# Mutate a column to perform operation that takes only numerical values does not return new values after the operation

Tags: r

I have a df that looks like this:

```
fold_change_label il1 ifna ifn il12 il16
1             value    1.69            13.0258             5.0755  3.3068     1.3
2             value    1.71                1.7             2.2711  3.9335    2.49
3            median    5.12 6.9399999999999995 7.1400000000000006    2.16     0.4
```

I'm performing and operation by each column with the following code:

```
test <- temp_fold_change %>%
  group_by(fold_change_label) %>%
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), 
                ~ if_else(fold_change_label == "value", .x / .x[fold_change_label == "median"], .x),
                .names = "{.col}_fch"))
```

The if_else statement that I'm trying to apply check if the label in the column `fold_change_label` is `value`, in that case I need to perform the following operation by column:

```
value / value labelled as median in that column
```

this operation for the first numerical column:

```
1.69 / 5.12 = 0.3300781
1.71 / 5.12 = 0.3339844
5.12 / 5.12 = NOT PERFORM THE OPERATION because you have the value labelled as "median"
```

Then, the result must be add in a new column with the name of the old column plus the string "_fch".

My issue with my code is doing nothing, no operation at all and no new columns added.

Questions:

- What I'm doing wrong?
- Is there a better approach to accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The grouping is not necessary:

```r
  temp_fold_change = read.table(text = "fold_change_label il1 ifna ifn il12 il16
1             value    1.69            13.0258             5.0755  3.3068     1.3
2             value    1.71                1.7             2.2711  3.9335    2.49
3            median    5.12 6.9399999999999995 7.1400000000000006    2.16     0.4", header = TRUE)
  
  library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
  temp_fold_change %>%
    mutate(across(where(is.numeric), 
                  ~ if_else(fold_change_label == "value", .x / .x[fold_change_label == "median"], .x),
                  .names = "{col}_fch"))
#>   fold_change_label  il1    ifna    ifn   il12 il16   il1_fch  ifna_fch
#> 1             value 1.69 13.0258 5.0755 3.3068 1.30 0.3300781 1.8769164
#> 2             value 1.71  1.7000 2.2711 3.9335 2.49 0.3339844 0.2449568
#> 3            median 5.12  6.9400 7.1400 2.1600 0.40 5.1200000 6.9400000
#>     ifn_fch il12_fch il16_fch
#> 1 0.7108543 1.530926    3.250
#> 2 0.3180812 1.821065    6.225
#> 3 7.1400000 2.160000    0.400
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for sharing a potential solution, I do not know why in my df is not updating, even if I copy-paste your idea. By the way, why you are no using ```group_by()```?

Comment: Restart your R session. Replace the code. Try again. Just run the code of this answer to see if that prints something to your console. Also, you need to run/execute `test` as you are assigning your operation to `test`.

Comment: I think that I know why is not working, all my data is ```chr```, and must be ```chr``` for the first column and the rest ```integer```, could you print what say in your console if you put str(temp_fold_change)? please

Comment: I don't understand. If the current toy data does not mimic your real data, replace it.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I do not know in what moment my data change!

Comment: It is good practice to regularly run code in a fresh R session.